# Mock a method call with void return type using JMockit or Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, jmockit

I have a very different kind of method call which I need to test using JMockit testing framework. First let us look at the code.

```
public class MyClass{

   MyPort port;       

   public registerMethod(){
       Holder<String> status=null;
       Holder<String> message=null;

       //below method call is a call to a webservice in the real implementation using apache cxf framework. This method has a void return type. Read below for better explanation.
       port.registerService("name", "country", "email", status, message);

       // do some stuff with status and message here.....

       HashMap response = new HashMap();
       response.put(status);
       response.put(message);

       return response;
   }  

}
```

Now let me explain the a little bit. This class is basically having a port instance variable which is used to connect to a webservice. The webservice implementation uses auto generated apache cxf framework classes to make connection to the webservice and get the response back. My job is to implement the mocking of this webservice call for writing testcases for lot many similar calls that are there in the real application.

The problem here is - If you notice that call to the webservice is actually made by the method port.registerService by sending name, country and email as the parameters. Now we also pass the status and message variables as the parameters themselves to this method. So this method instead of returning some value for status and message, it FILLS IN values in these two passed parameters which is very different from the "RETURN" approach.

Now the problem is when I m trying to mock this call using jmockit, I can always mock this call but what is to be expected ?? as there is no return at all, it turns out to be a void call which fills in values in the parameters passed to it. So I will always get status, and message as null if I mock this call as I cannot state any return expectation in the jmockit implementation.

Please if anybody has any solutions/suggestions to the above problem, do respond and try to help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can simulate the behavior of the mocked `port.registerService(...)` method with a `result = new Delegate() { void delegate(...) { ... } };` recording on the expectation. That would allow the test to specify desired side effects. But without seeing the complete method under test, I can't say for sure if this is what you need...

Comment: The problem here is that the actual method call just sets the values in the variables in the status and message variables without returning anything.

Comment: Yes, but so what? I don't understand. If the method is being mocked, it doesn't matter what its implementation does. In any case, your test has full control of the behavior of any mocked methods.

Comment: thanks for commenting rogerio. My point is, please look at the code above, in the line where I call port.registerService(...), I pass the parameters, status and message as well. Now after this call I am using these variables in the code to set some other stuff using these values. However, in case of mocking, this will always remain null and since these values are set inside the void method and NOT returned, hence I cannot set these values using expectations in the jmockit.

Comment: Your example code won't even compile, since `status` and `message` are read without ever being assigned. If you can show a method to be tested which actually compiles, I might be able to help.

Comment: edited the string local var declarations, however thats not the point to be discussed.

Comment: Yes, the local variables will remain `null` if they are never assigned with anything else. I still don't see the problem. As I said before, from your test you do have full control over the behavior of mocked methods, including `registerService`. Mocking cannot reach into a local variable inside a method and set it...

Comment: I got your point, but just wanted to be double sure. The actual type of the status and message variables is of type Holder which holds String values inside.
In the real call, when I call port.registerService(..., status, message) method, the variables status and message declared as null gets passed as parameters and this method then sets values in these variables and then I can use the value set in status and message Holder objects after that call.
So just wanted to be sure whether is it possible to set these variables with some values with the mock call as well ?

Comment: In that case, `status` and `message` would never be null when calling `port.registerService` (or you would get a NullPointerException). So, assuming they are properly initialized to `Holder` objects before that call, you can simulate the setting of values into them with a `Delegate` object, as I described in the first comment above.

Comment: Maybe author can post the solution or an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure what the `Holder` interface looked like so I made some assumptions. But, this is how you mock a method with a void return type using Mockito:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public final void test() {
    // given
    final String expectedStatus = "status";
    final String expectedMessage = "message";
    final MyPort mockPort = mock(MyPort.class);
    final Answer<Void> registerAnswer = new Answer<Void>() { // actual parameter type doesn't matter because it's a void method
        public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            // Here I'm stubbing out the behaviour of registerService
            final Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
            // I don't actually care about these, but if you wanted the other parameters, this is how you would get them
            // if you wanted to, you could perform assertions on them
            final String name = (String) arguments[0];
            final String country = (String) arguments[1];
            final String email = (String) arguments[2];

            final Holder<String> statusHolder = (Holder<String>) arguments[3];
            final Holder<String> messageHolder = (Holder<String>) arguments[4];
            statusHolder.put(expectedStatus);
            messageHolder.put(expectedMessage);
            // even though it's a void method, we need to return something
            return null;
        }
    };
    doAnswer(registerAnswer).when(mockPort).registerService(anyString(),
            anyString(), anyString(), any(Holder.class), any(Holder.class));

    final MyClass object = new MyClass();
    object.port = mockPort;

    // when
    final Map<String, String> result = object.registerMethod();

    // then
    assertEquals(expectedStatus, result.get("status"));
    assertEquals(expectedMessage, result.get("message"));
}
```

For reference, these are my imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
```